# C# SQL and LINQ duplicatekeyexception adding a record.....newbie

Tags: c#, sql, linq, record

I have a database with this tables:

```
PERSON ==> id=>int_primarykey(asc) name=>nchar(20) town=>nchar(20)
EMAIL ==> id=>primarykey(asc) idperson=>int mailaddress=>nchar(20)
telephone ==> id=>primarykey(asc) idperson=>int telnumber=>nchar(20)
```

So I have added in a form a datagrid with a binding navigator.
The problem is that when I try to add a new record, in the datagrid I have always id=0 and when I try to save the new record I have returned duplicatekeyexception because this id already exist.

How can I implement autoincrement for id? Here is the class:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Rubrica
{
        using System.Data.Linq;
        using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Reflection;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Linq.Expressions;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System;


        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="rubrica")]
        public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
        {

                private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void Insertemail(email instance);
    partial void Updateemail(email instance);
    partial void Deleteemail(email instance);
    partial void Insertpersona(persona instance);
    partial void Updatepersona(persona instance);
    partial void Deletepersona(persona instance);
    partial void Inserttelefono(telefono instance);
    partial void Updatetelefono(telefono instance);
    partial void Deletetelefono(telefono instance);
    #endregion

                public DataClasses1DataContext() : 
                                base(global::Rubrica.Properties.Settings.Default.rubricaConnectionString, mappingSource)
                {
                        OnCreated();
                }

                public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection) : 
                                base(connection, mappingSource)
                {
                        OnCreated();
                }

                public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
                                base(connection, mappingSource)
                {
                        OnCreated();
                }

                public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                                base(connection, mappingSource)
                {
                        OnCreated();
                }

                public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                                base(connection, mappingSource)
                {
                        OnCreated();
                }

                public System.Data.Linq.Table<email> emails
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this.GetTable<email>();
                        }
                }

                public System.Data.Linq.Table<persona> personas
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this.GetTable<persona>();
                        }
                }

                public System.Data.Linq.Table<telefono> telefonos
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this.GetTable<telefono>();
                        }
                }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.email")]
        public partial class email : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

                private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

                private int _idpersona;

                private string _mail;

                private int _id;

                private EntityRef<persona> _persona;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnidpersonaChanging(int value);
    partial void OnidpersonaChanged();
    partial void OnmailChanging(string value);
    partial void OnmailChanged();
    partial void OnidChanging(int value);
    partial void OnidChanged();
    #endregion

                public email()
                {
                        this._persona = default(EntityRef<persona>);
                        OnCreated();
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_idpersona", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
                public int idpersona
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._idpersona;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._idpersona != value))
                                {
                                        if (this._persona.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                                        {
                                                throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                                        }
                                        this.OnidpersonaChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._idpersona = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("idpersona");
                                        this.OnidpersonaChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="email", Storage="_mail", DbType="NChar(20) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
                public string mail
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._mail;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._mail != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnmailChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._mail = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("mail");
                                        this.OnmailChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
                public int id
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._id;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._id != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnidChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._id = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("id");
                                        this.OnidChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="persona_email", Storage="_persona", ThisKey="idpersona", OtherKey="id", IsForeignKey=true)]
                public persona persona
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._persona.Entity;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                persona previousValue = this._persona.Entity;
                                if (((previousValue != value) 
                                                        || (this._persona.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                                {
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        if ((previousValue != null))
                                        {
                                                this._persona.Entity = null;
                                                previousValue.emails.Remove(this);
                                        }
                                        this._persona.Entity = value;
                                        if ((value != null))
                                        {
                                                value.emails.Add(this);
                                                this._idpersona = value.id;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                this._idpersona = default(int);
                                        }
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("persona");
                                }
                        }
                }

                public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
                        }
                }

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                        }
                }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.persona")]
        public partial class persona : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

                private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

                private int _id;

                private string _nome;

                private string _cognome;

                private string _indirizzo;

                private EntitySet<email> _emails;

                private EntitySet<telefono> _telefonos;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnidChanging(int value);
    partial void OnidChanged();
    partial void OnnomeChanging(string value);
    partial void OnnomeChanged();
    partial void OncognomeChanging(string value);
    partial void OncognomeChanged();
    partial void OnindirizzoChanging(string value);
    partial void OnindirizzoChanged();
    #endregion

                public persona()
                {
                        this._emails = new EntitySet<email>(new Action<email>(this.attach_emails), new Action<email>(this.detach_emails));
                        this._telefonos = new EntitySet<telefono>(new Action<telefono>(this.attach_telefonos), new Action<telefono>(this.detach_telefonos));
                        OnCreated();
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
                public int id
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._id;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._id != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnidChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._id = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("id");
                                        this.OnidChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_nome", DbType="NChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
                public string nome
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._nome;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._nome != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnnomeChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._nome = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("nome");
                                        this.OnnomeChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_cognome", DbType="NChar(15) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
                public string cognome
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._cognome;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._cognome != value))
                                {
                                        this.OncognomeChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._cognome = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("cognome");
                                        this.OncognomeChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_indirizzo", DbType="NChar(50)")]
                public string indirizzo
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._indirizzo;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._indirizzo != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnindirizzoChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._indirizzo = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("indirizzo");
                                        this.OnindirizzoChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="persona_email", Storage="_emails", ThisKey="id", OtherKey="idpersona")]
                public EntitySet<email> emails
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._emails;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                this._emails.Assign(value);
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="persona_telefono", Storage="_telefonos", ThisKey="id", OtherKey="idpersona")]
                public EntitySet<telefono> telefonos
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._telefonos;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                this._telefonos.Assign(value);
                        }
                }

                public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
                        }
                }

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                        }
                }

                private void attach_emails(email entity)
                {
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        entity.persona = this;
                }

                private void detach_emails(email entity)
                {
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        entity.persona = null;
                }

                private void attach_telefonos(telefono entity)
                {
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        entity.persona = this;
                }

                private void detach_telefonos(telefono entity)
                {
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        entity.persona = null;
                }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.telefono")]
        public partial class telefono : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

                private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

                private int _id;

                private string _numero;

                private int _idpersona;

                private EntityRef<persona> _persona;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnidChanging(int value);
    partial void OnidChanged();
    partial void OnnumeroChanging(string value);
    partial void OnnumeroChanged();
    partial void OnidpersonaChanging(int value);
    partial void OnidpersonaChanged();
    #endregion

                public telefono()
                {
                        this._persona = default(EntityRef<persona>);
                        OnCreated();
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
                public int id
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._id;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._id != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnidChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._id = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("id");
                                        this.OnidChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="telefono", Storage="_numero", DbType="NChar(20) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
                public string numero
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._numero;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._numero != value))
                                {
                                        this.OnnumeroChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._numero = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("numero");
                                        this.OnnumeroChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_idpersona", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
                public int idpersona
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._idpersona;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                if ((this._idpersona != value))
                                {
                                        if (this._persona.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                                        {
                                                throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                                        }
                                        this.OnidpersonaChanging(value);
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        this._idpersona = value;
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("idpersona");
                                        this.OnidpersonaChanged();
                                }
                        }
                }

                [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="persona_telefono", Storage="_persona", ThisKey="idpersona", OtherKey="id", IsForeignKey=true)]
                public persona persona
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return this._persona.Entity;
                        }
                        set
                        {
                                persona previousValue = this._persona.Entity;
                                if (((previousValue != value) 
                                                        || (this._persona.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                                {
                                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                                        if ((previousValue != null))
                                        {
                                                this._persona.Entity = null;
                                                previousValue.telefonos.Remove(this);
                                        }
                                        this._persona.Entity = value;
                                        if ((value != null))
                                        {
                                                value.telefonos.Add(this);
                                                this._idpersona = value.id;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                this._idpersona = default(int);
                                        }
                                        this.SendPropertyChanged("persona");
                                }
                        }
                }

                public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
                        }
                }

                protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
                {
                        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
                        {
                                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                        }
                }
        }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Comment: What database engine do you use? Different dbms have their own mechanisms for autoincrementing identity.

Comment: microsoft sql express server v.10.00.2531 do you mean this? thank again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing this attributes:

```
AutoSync onInsert
ServerExplorer => table xx => field => Identity=true
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the best answer if you feel your question has been appropriately answered.